# C program: Binary tree

Tags: c

I need some help with creating a binary tree program. Basically, I have different methods for creating and using a binary tree table (insert, find etc). The methods are called from other classes. Right now I don't think my insert function is working properly since when I print the table out it only shows the last node of the tree.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define __USE_BSD
#include <string.h>

#include "speller.h"
#include "dict.h"

typedef struct node *tree_ptr;
struct node {
    Key_Type element; // only data is the key itself
    tree_ptr left, right;
    // add anything else that you need
};

struct table {
    tree_ptr head; // points to the head of the tree
    // add anything else that you need
};

Table initialize_table(/*ignore parameter*/) {
    Table newTable = malloc(sizeof(Table));
    newTable->head = NULL;
    return newTable;
}

void insert_again(Key_Type key, tree_ptr node) {
    Key_Type currentKey = node->element;
    //printf("%s\n%s", currentKey, key);
    int keyCompare = strcmp(key, currentKey);
    // Move to the left node.
    if (keyCompare < 0) {
        //printf("%s\n%s", currentKey, key);
        // If left node is empty, create a new node.
        if (node->left == NULL) {
            tree_ptr newPtr = malloc(sizeof(tree_ptr));
            newPtr->element = key;
            newPtr->left = NULL;
            newPtr->right = NULL;
            node->left = newPtr;
        } else {
            insert_again(key, node->left);
        }
    }
    // Move to the right node.
    else if (keyCompare > 0) {
        //printf("%s\n%s", currentKey, key);
        // If right node is empty, create a new node.
        if (node->right == NULL) {
            tree_ptr newPtr = malloc(sizeof(tree_ptr));
            newPtr->element = key;
            newPtr->left = NULL;
            newPtr->right = NULL;
            node->right = newPtr;
        } else {
            insert_again(key, node->right);
        }
    }
}

Table insert(Key_Type key, Table table) {
    // if it's a new tree.
    if (table->head == NULL) {
        tree_ptr headPtr = malloc(sizeof(tree_ptr));
        headPtr->element = key;
        headPtr->left = NULL;
        headPtr->right = NULL;
        table->head = headPtr;
        //printf("%s", table->head->element);
    }
    // if the tree already exists
    else {
        //printf("%s", table->head->element);
        insert_again(key, table->head);
    }
    //printf("%s", table->head->element);
    return table;
}

Boolean find_key(Key_Type key, tree_ptr node) {
    Key_Type currentKey = node->element;
    int keyCompare = strcmp(key, currentKey);
    if (node != NULL) {
        if (keyCompare == 0) {
            return TRUE;
        } else
        if (keyCompare == -1) {
            return find_key(key, node->left);
        } else {
            return find_key(key, node->right);
        }
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}

Boolean find(Key_Type key, Table table) {
    return find_key(key, table->head);
}

void print_tree(tree_ptr node) {
    if (node == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    print_tree(node->left);
    printf("%s\n", node->element);
    print_tree(node->right);
}

void print_table(Table table) {
    print_tree(table->head);
}

void print_stats(Table table) {
}
```

Comment: Oh, that's too bad. Have a cookie? Joking aside, include a smallest possible compilable program exhibiting the problem. And please let us know what have you already tried. Currently it sounds suspiciously like "do this for me", which doesn't offer educational value to ... anyone.

Comment: Looks like some of my earlier computer science program projects. My best advice is to try to avoid being clever as long as possible(you can add cleverness later/rewrite once it works), and try to keep working code separate from code you're not sure about. Stepping through your code with gdb should help. if discouraged you can look over https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle (Not to learn how to do things, but for comical relief).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to search for an empty child node to insert a new node into a tree. Use a pointer to a pointer to notice the empty child node. Apart from this you have to allocate memory for `sizeof(struct node)`and not for `sizeof(struct node*)` as you did. In relation to the code I can see, that type of `Key_Type` is `char*`. So you have to use `strcmp` to compare keys and you have to allocate memory and to copy the key into the node.

```
Boolean insert( Key_Type key, Table table ) 
{
   tree_ptr *ppNode = &(table->head); // pointer to pointer to node (struct node **)
   while ( ppNode != NULL )
   {
      int keyCompare = strcmp( key, (*ppNode)->element );
      if ( keyCompare == 0 )
          return FALSE; // element with key is already member of tree

      if ( keyCompare < 0 )
          ppNode = &((*ppNode)->left);  // go to left child
      else 
          ppNode = &((*ppNode)->right); // go to right child
   }

   // now ppNode is either a pointer to an empty child pointer,
   // or to table->head if the tree is empty

   *ppNode = malloc( sizeof(struct node) ); // allocate new node right to target
   (*ppNode)->left = NULL;
   (*ppNode)->right = NULL;
   (*ppNode)->element = malloc( strlen(key) + 1 );
   strcpy( (*ppNode)->element, key );

   return TRUE; // new node added successfully
}
```

Finding a node with `key` is similar to find an empty child pointer:

```
Boolean find_key( Key_Type key, Table table ) 
{
   tree_ptr pNode = table->head;
   while ( ppNode != NULL )
   {
      int keyCompare = strcmp( key, pNode->element );
      if ( keyCompare == 0 )
          return TRUE; // element with key was found

      if ( keyCompare < 0 )
          pNode = pNode->left;  // go to left child
      else 
          pNode = pNode->right; // go to right child
   }
   return FALSE; // key is not member of tree
}
```